# What HTTP return code in the request for empty result 204 or 404?

Tags: rest, http

I have a call with a return object, but this call may return an empty result.

My URL in controller is:

```
/api/find-by-id/{id}
```

This controller make calls service as the following:

```
service.findById(Integer id);
```

My sevice searches through DAO:

```
repository.findById(Integer id);
```

When DAO return an empty value, should I send error `HTTP 404` or `HTTP 204` to front?

Considering:

- 2xx: Success - The action was successfully received,
  understood, and accepted
- 4xx: Client Error - The request contains bad syntax or cannot
  be fulfilled

`HTTP 204`: Means that something was found, but it's empty.

`HTTP 404`: Not found.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty value"? Is there a semantic difference in your design between "empty value" and "no value for id"? If there is no difference then 404. If there is then it is obvious what to do.

Answer (score 2):

If your `findById` always returns exactly 0 or 1 items, and this is your request:

```
GET /api/find-by-id/{id}
```

Then I believe that the result should be 404 if an item does not exist.

`204` is different. It doesn't really imply an item doesn't exist, it implies that the operation was a success, but the result is empty + a hypermedia client should not refresh the current view. It's rarely used as a response to `GET` request because it doesn't make that much sense.

Since it sounds like you're using a database, the equivalent to `204` / empty would be a database record with that id, but all the fields are `null`. The equivalent to `404` would be that the database record does not exist at all.

Answer (score 1):

> What HTTP return code in the request for empty result 204 or 404?

A possibly useful analogy - imagine looking up a file on a file system.

- If I find the file, and it is zero bytes long -> 204.
- If I don't find the file at all -> 404.

[204](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) specifically describes the content-body of the response; that the body is zero bytes long.  So `204` is not appropriate, for example, if you are sending an application/json representation of an empty object.

```
{}
```

Instead, you would use one of the other 2xx response codes (probably 200).

[404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) is "I can't find it - did you spell the URL wrong?"

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

The repository pattern was described by Evans as providing the calling code with the illusion that all objects are being held in an in memory collection.  So if "empty value" means "the id doesn't match an item in the collection", then `404` is a good choice.

If the id did retrieve an item, but the body of the response is zero bytes long (because the item is empty, or whatever), then `204` is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the api and the result is empty the code still is 202 or 204 if you want cataloger,

when you do the request and doesn't exist it is a 404 , most common in dead, broken or wrong link.

your controller or services need to do a action when is 204, like redirect to a 404 page.